# Priority of revision types in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

In a mercurial repo you can have a branch, tag and bookmark all with the same name. Which do you get if you do

```
hg update foo
```

or

```
hg clone --updaterev foo somerepo
```

I.e. what is the priority between branches, tags and bookmarks?
Experiments show the order to be bookmark - tag - branch, but I can not find documentation for this. Can I rely on this?

From `hg help revsets` you can find syntax to specify what you mean, e.g. `branch(foo)` (may need quotes depending on the name and also the shell).

Comment: It took no more then a couple minutes to init a new mercurial repository in an empty test directory and try it out it to discover that `hg update foo` went to the bookmark. You should have tried it out *before* asking (or if you did, [you should have mentioned it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Now, if your question is instead "I observed <some behaviour>, can I rely on that? Where is it documented?" that would be different.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have previously researched it quite a bit, and my question is actually if I can rely on the observed behaviour. Question edited.