# Mercurial: explicitly specifying branch/tag/bookmark when cloning

Tags: mercurial

In a mercurial repo you can have a branch, tag and bookmark all with the same name. `hg help revsets` tells you how to specify this explicitly. I get this to work with e.g.

```
hg update 'branch(foo)'
```

but not with

```
hg clone --updaterev 'branch(foo)' somerepo
```

This gives the error `abort: unknown revision 'branch(foo)'!`, even though

```
hg clone --updaterev 'foo' somerepo
```

works fine (gives me the branch) as long as there are no name conflicts. I observe the same for tags.
Is there a way to explicitly specify a branch/tag/bookmark directly when cloning?

Comment: very near duplicate of [Priority of revision types in mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920995/priority-of-revision-types-in-mercurial).

Comment: Though related, they are two different questions. I decided to specifically ask them separately to avoid getting answers that address only one part, which makes it easy to overlook that there are still unanswered issues left. I have tried to elaborate to make the question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- understand the difference between revset and single revision in Mercurial
- understand that `--updaterev` use revsets language (`hg help revsets`) behind the scenes and branch (ID) will return revset with **all changesets** in revision, but `--updaterev` require **single changeset**

I'm too lazy to test `--updaterev` for repo with all 3 objects in it at the same time, but (for branch case) `--updaterev 'foo'` defines head of foo internally before action

> Is there a way to explicitly specify a branch/tag/bookmark directly
>   when cloning?

Yes. Just use *correct predicates* in revset-definition, which uniquely identify one needed for you at every time changeset

- Branch: `branch(foo) and head()` or, in case of multi-heads branch, something like `last(heads(branch(foo)))`
- Bookmarks: `bookmark(foo)`
- Tag: `tag(foo)`

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it does indeed make sense. 
However, I still can't get revsets language to work with clone, e.g.: 
`hg clone --updaterev "rev(1)" somerepo` gives the same error (`abort: unknown revision 'rev(1)'!`).
`hg clone --updaterev "1" somerepo` works fine.
I am using hg version 3.1.

Comment: @TrygveFlathen - why not just `hg clone --rev 1`, which works?

Comment: `--rev` is not the same as `--updaterev`:
updaterev will clone the entire repo and then check out the given revision, while rev will only clone the given revision and the relevant history.
(I just used `rev()` here as a simple example to illustrate the problem with using revset language with `--updaterev`.)

Comment: Yes, but "1" and "rev(1)" was just used as a simple example to illustrate that I don't get the revsets language to work with --updaterev. I want to clone and have a specific branch/tag/bookmark checked out, even when there may be name conflicts. Your initial answer would be perfect except I can't get that syntax to work with --updaterev.